# How to create a nested list model in Backbone

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I want  to use Backbone to create a menu like below

- news

  - local

    - 1st news
    - 2nd news
  - global

    - 1st news
    - 2nd news
- story

I have written some code as below but it doesn't work.

```
//create a menu which has a list of item
var MenuList = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
     relations: [{
         type: Backbone.HasMany,
         key: 'itemList',
         relatedModel: 'MenuItem',
         reverseRelation: {
             key: 'upperItem',
             },
     }]

});

//each item can be menu list
var MenuItem = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
     relations: [{
         type: Backbone.HasOne,
         key: 'subMenu',
         relatedModel: 'MenuList',
         reverseRelation: {
             key: 'upperItem',
             },
     }]

});
```

Any help will be very appreciated. Or any framework based on backbone can meet the requirement? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to use Backbone?

Comment: Does the content of your menu come from an API or something? If not why do you want to use a framework for a simple menu? I don't see any benefit.